Adding documents to Vector store failing with Authentication Error
I am trying to follow the tutorial given in this link , to visualise the RAG data using renumics-spotlight package.
I've set the open API key using the step mentioned as
%env OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-proj-*****"

When running the code to add the documents to vector store(Chroma) in this case, I keep getting Authentication error
Code that is erroring :
import hashlib
import json
from langchain_core.documents import Document

def stable_hash(doc: Document) -> str:
    """
    Stable hash document based on its metadata.
    """
    return hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(doc.metadata, sort_keys=True).encode()).hexdigest()
    
split_ids = list(map(stable_hash, splits))
docs_vectorstore.add_documents(splits, ids=split_ids)
docs_vectorstore.persist()

And the full error can be found here link

Update these lines of code and include the api_key in them:
openai.api_key = 'your-api-key'
# Initialize the embeddings model
embeddings_model = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002", openai_api_key=openai.api_key)
llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4", temperature=0.0, openai_api_key=openai.api_key)

